# Recursively add value if within range

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm sure that this should be really simple but I can't seem to get this to work. Basically I want to check if a date falls on a weekend or a bank holiday and if it does then add a day to the date and check again and so until the date doesn't fall on one of these two and then return the date. So I have:

```
    private static DateTime isBankHoliday(DateTime myDate)
    {

        if (DateSystem.IsPublicHoliday(myDate, CountryCode.GB) || DateSystem.IsWeekend(myDate, CountryCode.GB))
        {
            isBankHoliday(myDate.AddDays(1));
        }
        else
        {
            return myDate;
        }

        return myDate;
    }
```

And I call this function

```
var myNewDate = isBankHoliday(date);
```

So say for instance I pass in the 5th May 2019 (Sunday) the routine checks and then adds a day to the date so becoming the 6th and checks again but somewhere along the line the date then reverts back and returns the 5th again.

Obviously I've made some basic error somewhere but just can't see it could someone assist please?

As a note I'm using the Nagar date library.

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `return` in the `if` statement, and you're got an incorrect `return` statement at the end of the function. It should be:

```
private static DateTime isBankHoliday(DateTime myDate)
{

    if (DateSystem.IsPublicHoliday(myDate, CountryCode.GB) || DateSystem.IsWeekend(myDate, CountryCode.GB))
    {
        return isBankHoliday(myDate.AddDays(1));
    }
    else
    {
        return myDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it important to you to do it recursively?  You could do it more simply with a while loop:

```
private static DateTime isBankHoliday(DateTime myDate)
{
    while (DateSystem.IsPublicHoliday(myDate, CountryCode.GB)
            || DateSystem.IsWeekend(myDate, CountryCode.GB))
    {
        myDate = myDate.AddDays(1);
    }

    return myDate;
}
```